# How I can link between JADE agent with the OPC

Tags: agents-jade

How I can link between Agent and OPC? Because when I add the Agent code, JAVA cannot connect the OPC. Thank you

```
public class G2P extends Agent{
  //Agent initializations
  protected void setup() {
    // Printout a welcome message
    System.out.println("G2-agent "+getAID().getName()+" is ready.");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // create connection information
    final ConnectionInformation ci = new ConnectionInformation();

    ci.setHost("");
    ci.setDomain("");
    ci.setUser("");
    ci.setPassword("");
    ci.setClsid("F8582CF2-88FB-11D0-B850-00C0F0104305"); 
    final String itemId1 = "....";

    // create a new server
    final Server server = new Server(ci, Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
    try {
        // connect to server
        server.connect();
        // add sync access, poll every 500 ms
        final AccessBase access = new SyncAccess(server, 500);
        access.addItem(itemId1, new DataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void changed(Item item, ItemState state) {
                // also dump value
                try {
                    if (state.getValue().getType() == JIVariant.VT_UI4) {
                        System.out.println("<<< " + state + " / value = " + state.getValue().getObjectAsUnsigned().getValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("<<< " + state + " / value = " + state.getValue().getObject());
                    }
                } catch (JIException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Add a new group
        final Group group = server.addGroup("test");
        // Add a new item to the group
        final Item item = group.addItem(itemId1);

        // start reading
        access.bind();

        // add a thread for writing a value every 3 seconds
        ScheduledExecutorService writeThread = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        writeThread.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JIVariant value = new JIVariant(i.incrementAndGet());
                try {
                    System.out.println(">>> " + "writing value " + i.get());
                    item.write(value);
                } catch (JIException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 5, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // wait a little bit
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
        writeThread.shutdownNow();
        // stop reading
        access.unbind();
    } catch (final JIException e) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%08X: %s", e.getErrorCode(), server.getErrorMessage(e.getErrorCode())));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not have any error message in the program. This is the message that I got "http://192.168.201.36:7778/acc
G2-agent G2@192.168.201.36:1099/JADE is ready.
B2-agent B2@192.168.201.36:1099/JADE is ready.
Dec 18, 2015 7:12:01 AM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: --------------------------------------
Agent container Main-Container@192.168.201.36 is ready.
--------------------------------------------"